# Is there an API to create a Certificate Signing Request with POCO library

Tags: poco-libraries, csr

I am trying to create a CSR using POCO library. I am able to create a key pair using Poco/Crypto/RSAKey.h RSA() function. Is there a way CSR can be created using the key pair generated.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Not through Poco NetSSL interface but, if you are inclined to contribute, it should not be too hard to wrap the functionality. See [mkreq.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/x509/mkreq.c).

Comment: hi can u give brief pointers to how can I contribute and extend Poco in building a CSR using Openssl.

Comment: See [Contributing](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md)